# How to add and use custom context parameters during parsing with F# FsYacc?

Tags: parsing, f#, fsyacc

I'm using *FsLex* and *FsYacc* for string parsing in F# application. During Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) creation parser has to do a decision how to create the AST (make different trees, throw an exception, etc).
The parser behaviour must depend on several parameters.

[Here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FsYacc) I've found that it is allowed to declare something like:

```
%type < (context -> context) > toplevel
```

But I could not find how to use this construction and during project compilation have *"fsyacc.exe" exited with code 1."* error

The **Question** is: is it possible and how to use context parameters during parsing with FsYacc?

**Example** of what I've tried:

```
%start startAst

%type < (bool -> MyAst) > startAst

%%   

startAst:
| MyAst EOF { 
                    (fun (x : bool) -> 
                        if x then 
                            MyAst.Type1 $1 
                        else 
                            MyAst.Type2) 
                }
...
```

and I've expected usage something like this:

```
let lexbuf = Lexing.LexBuffer<char>.FromString text
lexbuf |> Lexer.tokenize |> Parser.startAst (ctx: bool)
```

Thanks in advance

**Update** following exception and call stack is generated during fsyacc.exe execution:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: more than one input given
   at FSharp.PowerPack.FsYacc.Driver.clo@67-5.Invoke(String x)
   at <StartupCode$fsyacc>.$Arg.findMatchingArg$cont@104-1(FSharpRef`1 cursor, FSharpFunc`2 other, String usageText, FSharpList`1 argSpecs, String arg, Unit unitVar)
   at <StartupCode$fsyacc>.$Arg.findMatchingArg@64(FSharpRef`1 cursor, String[] argv, FSharpFunc`2 other, String usageText, Int32 nargs, FSharpList`1 argSpecs, String arg, FSharpList`1 args)
   at Internal.Utilities.ArgParser.ParsePartial(FSharpRef`1 cursor, String[] argv, IEnumerable`1 arguments, FSharpOption`1 otherArgs, FSharpOption`1 usageText)
   at Internal.Utilities.ArgParser.Parse(IEnumerable`1 arguments, FSharpOption`1 otherArgs, FSharpOption`1 usageText)
   at <StartupCode$fsyacc>.$FSharp.PowerPack.FsYacc.Driver.main@()
```

Comment: If you run `fsyacc.exe` manually (through the command-line), you'll get a nice friendly error. Please do so, and post here.

Comment: Currently I have only "fsyacc.exe has stopped working" exception without any log information

Comment: I sure that my code is incorrect? but I don;t know how correctly use it with FsYacc - probably somebody will provide me with useful link (even to OCaml Yacc example, where it is used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay, but finally got around to this.

Whoever wrote FsYacc (the F# team?) missed the functions, as can be seen by their own comment on the page you linked. I tried several variations, but this is the only one I was able to make work (note: this requires either a `#nowarn "62"` in the `.fsy` file, which will propagate to the `.fs` file, or `--nowarn:62` for the whole project):

```
%{

open Ast

type ('a,'b) Fun = 'a -> 'b

%}

%start startAst

%token <string> MyAst
%token EOF

%type < (bool, MyAst) Fun > startAst

%%

startAst:
| MyAst EOF { (fun (x : bool) ->
                if x then
                    MyAst.Type1 $1
                else
                    MyAst.Type2) }
```

I got no  idea why (and don't have the time to go over FsYacc's source, at least not right now).

Comment: @Vitaliy glad to help. Reported it via CodePlex (and verified that the problem indeed lies in the FsYacc source code): http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/workitem/7025